# Port forwarding-can't open the routers web based configuration page

Tags: portforwarding

I want to forward the ftp port to allow FTP traffic.

but the problem is : nothing shows up when i enter my router's ip address in the browser's adress bar,

my default gateway is 172.16.212.1,and i tried every possible combination of addresses for my routers_web_based_config_page as suggested in google,
still no result.

(if there are any strange combinations,do let me know)

what could be the problem?

is it natural that there will be no web based configuration page for a router,sometimes???.

Comment: This is question for some other site, such as http://serverfault.com/. You should also add more info - what is the model of your router, your network configuration, etc. To answer your question - yes, it's quite natural for some routers not to have web-based interface. Standard home routers should have it, though.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question. Yes, it's quite natural for some routers not to have web-based interface. Standard home routers should have it, though.

What is the model of your router?

Is there a reset pinhole?? If yes then try pushing it.

If there is you should try that but before doing this you should clear history,  cache, and everything else. CTRL + SHIFT + DEL.